# What are the key things I need to learn before I can simulate graphene growth on a metal substrate using LAMMPS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, graphene

I am planning to conduct an MD simulation research on graphene growth on a metal substrate using lammps. I recently learned to form a crystal lattice using lammps. But I have no idea what to look for next. Any suggestions?

Comment: Start with simple systems, and play with all the important LAMMPS commands to understand how they work. LAMMPS already has an extensive list of exercises (https://github.com/lammps/lammps/tree/develop/examples) that you can explore. Then a good idea would be to replicate published results.

Comment: Anish, did you figure this out? Did you follow the advice of Magic_Number?